# how to echo each names one by one in php

Tags: php, arrays

how to echo them one by one

```
Array
(
    [Afghanistan] => Array
        (
            [53] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2020-3-15
                    [confirmed] => 16
                    [deaths] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                )

        )

    [Albania] => Array
        (
            [53] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2020-3-15
                    [confirmed] => 42
                    [deaths] => 1
                    [recovered] => 0
                )

        ) 
)
```

how to echo country name and its confirmed, deaths , recovered using a loop

like afganistan , confirmed , deaths , recovered.

My code:

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-n-d', strtotime("-10 days"));
    $json = file_get_contents('pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json', false);
    $arr = json_decode($json, true); // array to store all items with date specified
    $collection = [];
    foreach ($arr as $country => $dates) {
        $filtered = array_filter($dates, fn($obj) => $obj['date'] === $date);
        $collection = array_merge($collection, [$country => $filtered]);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection);
?>
```

Comment: `53` index will be always inside country array?

Comment: let me give you my code

Comment: <?php


$date = date('Y-n-d',strtotime("-10 days"));

  $json = file_get_contents('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json', false);

  $arr = json_decode($json, true);

  // array to store all items with date specified
  $collection = [];

  foreach ($arr as $country => $dates) {
    $filtered = array_filter($dates, fn ($obj) => $obj['date'] === $date);

    $collection = array_merge($collection, [$country => $filtered]);
  }






echo "<pre>";
  

  print_r($collection);


?> i want to echo $collection all values one by one

Comment: What does index `53` means?

Comment: it means 53rd index

Comment: @AksenP try the above code you will get the answers

Comment: @ganesh you haven't done a great job of expressing what your exact desired output should look like from your provided sample input.

Comment: @mickmackusa my apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use use `array_filter()` because it cannot enjoy the performance benefits of `break`.

It also doesn't make a lot of sense to call `array_merge()` if you want to add new items to your collection with associative keys.

```
$date = date('Y-n-d', strtotime("-10 days"));
$json = file_get_contents('pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json', false);
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$collection = [];
foreach ($arr as $country => $entry) {
    echo $country;
    foreach ($entry as $index => $details) {
        if ($details['date'] === $date)) {
            unset($details['date']);
            // $collection[$country] = $details; // omit the valueless index
            foreach ($details as $key => $value) {
                echo ", {$value} {$key}";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of your two sample countries:

```
Afghanistan, 16 confirmed, 0 deaths, 0 recovered
Albania, 42 confirmed, 1 deaths, 0 recovered
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach($collection as $country=>$data){
    echo "$country".PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data[53] as $key=>$val){
         echo "$key -> $val".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

*Note: it's OK in case if index `53` always would be in this collection.*

If it won't be always, then you can use next loop:

```
foreach($collection as $country=>$data){
    echo "$country".PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data as $set){
         foreach($set as $key=>$val){
              echo "$key -> $val".PHP_EOL;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a bit this chunk:

```
foreach ($arr as $country => $dates) {
    $dates = array_values($dates)[0]; // remove 53 index and init $dates with nested array
    $filtered = array_filter($dates, fn($obj) => $obj['date'] === $date);
    $collection = array_merge($collection, [$country => $filtered]);
}
```